# I am trying to setup apache storm cluster. I am asked to create host files what is slave1.foo.com?

Tags: ubuntu, cluster-computing, apache-storm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNaog.png)

I am trying to setup apache storm cluster. I am asked to create host files what is slave1.foo.com? And is it needed?

Answer (score 0):

It is the FQDN of your first worker. And yes, it is required.